# tcolorbox and table: adding a shadow to the table without padding

Tags: tables, tcolorbox, shadows, border

I'm trying to apply a shadow to a `longtabu` environment (because I want the table expands to fit the available width), similar to this table (CSS):

[image]

But, for my sample  LaTeX` table, between the shadow and the table, there's some border and padding and I don't know how to remove it:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}

\definecolor{lightgray}{RGB}{180, 180, 180}

\geometry{
  a4paper,
  margin=1cm,
  top=1.3cm,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,size=fbox,drop shadow]
  \begin{longtabu} to \textwidth {cXc}
    \rowcolor{Maroon}
    Imagen & Producto & Total\\
    \rowcolor{lightgray}
    A & B & C
  \end{longtabu}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In short, I want to remove the borders, to center the shadow, and to remove the padding between the shadow and the table, preferably with using standard packages or environments, but using custom commands is also fine.

Comment: Please provide a compilable document code, not just fragments

Comment: The `longtabu` is not necessary here

Comment: @ChristianHupfer But it must be a "longtable" environment, because the table could span more than one page when images add added to the table in the first column.

Comment: No, even in `tcolorbox` with `breakable`, the `longtabu` won't break any longer!

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to put the table inside a `TiKz` node:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw=none,shade,blur shadow={shadow blur steps=20, shadow xshift=0ex,shadow yshift=0ex, shadow blur radius=1ex},inner sep=0pt]
       {
         \begin{tabu}{>{\centering}m{0.2\textwidth}p{0.5\textwidth}>{\centering}p{0.2\textwidth}}
           \rowcolor{Maroon}
           \rowfont{\large\color{white}}
           & Producto & Total\\[0.8ex]
           \rowcolor{lightgray}
           \includegraphics[height=80px, width=0.18\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{icon.png} & B & J
         \end{tabu}
     };
\end{tikzpicture}
```